# WPF put ListView items DataTemplate to a separate file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, datatemplate

I have a simple task, but a little bit confused with it.
So, I have a ListView on some of my windows and I have a custom ListView item that I put in the separate file calls "ListViewItem.xaml" and I've made a custom style for my ListView in "Styles.Constrols.ListView.Xaml".
My "MyListViewItem.xaml" looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeApp.Views.MyListViewItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="40" 
             d:DesignWidth="400"
             Margin="0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Height="40" Width="60" Content="{Binding Id}" Foreground="Chartreuse"  />
        <ComboBox Margin="2 0 0 0" ItemsSource={Binding Values}/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

My "Styles.Constrols.ListView.Xaml" is:

```
  <Style x:Key="Style.ListViews.MainWindow.CenterPanel" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">     
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <views:MyListViewItem/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

At this moment all works fine BUT when I try to change the type of MyListViewItem from **UserControl** to **ListViewItem** I'm getting an error at this line

```
<DataTemplate>
   <views:MyListViewItem/>
</DataTemplate>
```

***property 'visual tree' does not support values of type "ListViewItem"***

When I do this little trick:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ListViewItem 
     xmlns....>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Height="40" Width="60" Content="{Binding Id}" Foreground="Chartreuse"  />
            <ComboBox Margin="2 0 0 0" ItemsSource={Binding Values}/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem >
</DataTemplate>
```

It becomes working fine.
What is the point of this behavior?

So my questions are as follows

- Is it so necessary to use UserControl for all elements that we want to put from window layout (for better readability) into separate .xaml file ?
- ListViewItem And UserControl are both children of ContentControl, why I can't use ListViewItem when I put its layout in separate file?

Comment: ListView always creates a ListViewItem for reach item (except the items in ItemsSource are already of type ListViewItem). It will then take the DataTemplate and wrap it into the ListViewItem. The ListViewItem is the item container that implements all the select and interaction behaviors. The DataTemplate is the content of the ListViewItem. Right now you are essentially wrapping a ListViewItem into a ListViewItem, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Generally, introducing a dedicated UserControl is not necessary. You can simply define the layout in the DataTemplate, then move this template to a dedicated file i.e. ResourceDictionary and merge it when necessary. Then reference the DataTemplate using StaticResource

Comment: @BionicCode thank for the answer, but if I define the layout in the DataTemplate and then move it to a dedicated file - how I can work with it in designer? It is a very handy thing to work with some element in XAML UI designer and I wouldn't want to give it up

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. You want to define an item template as resource. When you assign this resource to the ItemsControl.ItemTemplate property using StaticResource the designer will give you a preview if you bind design time data to the ItemsControl. Is this what you want?

Comment: And there is nothing wrong to wrap the layout into a UserControl. It just means extra work because you would have to introduce dependency properties for every data property that the DataTemplate depends on. But don't add a ListViewItem to the DataTemplate of a ListViewItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work.

**MyListViewItem.xaml:**

```
<ListViewItem x:Class="SomeApp.Views.MyListViewItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Height="40" Width="60" Content="{Binding Id}" Foreground="Chartreuse"  />
        <ComboBox Margin="2 0 0 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ListViewItem>
```

**MyListViewItem.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace SomeApp.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MyListViewItem.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyListViewItem : ListViewItem
    {
        public MyListViewItem()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

> Is it so necessary to use UserControl for all elements that we want to put from window layout (for better readability) into separate .xaml file ?

No.

> ListViewItem And UserControl are both children of ContentControl, why I can't use ListViewItem when I put its layout in separate file?

You can.

Comment: thx for the answer, BUT did you try to write a simple code to check that there isn't possible to use the ListViewItem control instead UserControl as ItemTemplate

Comment: Sorry, my fault, now I see where the problem was, your answer accepted